# Password confirm validation fails

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

HTML code:

```
<div id="form_pwd">          
<form method="POST" action="google.com" id="pwdChange">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="175px"><label for="newPwd">Enter your password</label></td>                
            <td><input type="password" name="newPwd" id="newPwd" size="35"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="newPwd_">Re-enter your password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="newPwd_" id="newPwd_" size="35"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save Password" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#form_pwd").validate(
    {
    rules:
    {
        newPwd: "required",
        newPwd_:
        {
        equalTo: "#newPwd"
        }
    }
    }
    );
}
);
```

I use the above source to validate my input passwords but there is nothing being shown next to the text boxes, would someone please have a look and help me spot it ?
i already include

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});
</script>
```

at the top of the file. :(

[**Update**]Ok, the demo is here
http://jsfiddle.net/Z9JmB/2/

I hope someone could help me out with this tiny problem. Thank you sooo much .

Comment: What exactly does `validate(...)` do, and where is it defined - does it come from a plugin?

Comment: And jQuery? did you include that (before)? Does the JS console (Firebug, Chrome's Dev Tool) show anything?

Comment: Ok, now I see that you are using the jquery validation plugin from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Start off with the source code example provided at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#source, and then modify it according to your needs. The example also loads the latest jQuery version, as mentioned by Damien.

Comment: Yes, it is, there are a lot of error reported in the console for the validate.js file. I would like to know if there are any possible ways to make this work,

Comment: I just added your html source to the question, so we have all in one place to look at.

Comment: @OhDude If you are satisfied by any of the answers check mark it with a upvote in it....this will inspire you to move ahead in Stsckoverflow and motivate the answering SO to answer more

Answer (score 3):

This works fine, but you're targeting the div outside of the form. You need to change the target element from:

```
$("#form_pwd")
```

to:

```
$("#pwdChange")
```

This will target your form.

Also, in your JS fiddle, you need to include your validation js file. I updated the jsfiddle to include the validation plugin your using, it all works 100% correctl, please have a look:

> http://jsfiddle.net/Z9JmB/5/

Comment: Oooppssss i didn't see that, thanks a lot for the nice spot offered. hahhahaha Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine. Make sure your password input has `id="newPwd"` or post more code. Maybe setup a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Also see manual http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo#other

Comment: I update to clearify, please link to jsfidddle.net above for more information to help me out